# Is there another way of installing an operating system from an ISO File without using Datastore ISO file

Tags: windows-7, installation, vmware-esx, iso, disk-image

I am trying to install a `Windows 7` on an empty virtual machine with the `VMware Infrastucture Client`. Because I do not have the image on the Datastore, I am looking for an alternative.

Is there another way of installing an operating system from an ISO File without using `Datastore ISO file`?

Comment: The ISO File is on another computer. I tried to use "Client Device" and tried to connect the CD/DVD to the ISO Image file immediately after starting the Machine with no success.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use anywhere your client can access. I keep an external hard drive for my laptop that contains duplicates of all my installers. Network locations work as well but it generally slows down the install process (share -> client -> server).

This is done with the same icon used to connect a datastore ISO. I believe that the client needs to be run with admin rights to see them however.

EDIT - see attached image.

[image: How To Attach Client Drive]

Comment: The options I can see are: Client Device, Host Device and Datastore ISO file.

Comment: You should be seeing the 'connect to ISO image on local disk..' option. If not (and you are running running on a Vista or higher OS) you need to run the client with admin rights to see the extra option. I'm assuming that you are running at least ESX 4.0, right?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `Datastore ISO file` option. My really problem was that the console window was completely white.
The problem I had is described in the following link: http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1026153